# Images in a bootstrap carousel not filling the carousel area

Tags: html, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am kind of new to ruby and recently installed the refile Gem to upload multiple photos. I wanted to display them in a Carousel format so I am using the Bootstrap carousel. However when displayed the Photo doesn't fill the carousel window and sticks to the left. This leaves the rest of the carousel window blank with the scrolling arrow off the picture. This is the way its displaying https://www.shyftworks.com/ambassadors/elise-craig I am not sure what to do. 
Here is also the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/farquhar86/3vy2547f/
This is my code on the show page:

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <% @ambassador.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <div class="item <%= 'active' if index == 0%>" data-slide-number="<%= index %>">
      <%=attachment_image_tag(image, :file, :fill, 600, 600, class: 'img-responsive') %>
    </div>
    <% end%>
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
<!-- end of carousel-->
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also if you have a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do it would be awesome!!!

Comment: This isn't enough to go on.  Can you make a fiddle of your problem?  Or point to a live demo where someone can help you debug? You'll need to include bootstrap, so maybe a starting point like this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Comment: This is the live site. Hope this helps: https://www.shyftworks.com/ambassadors/elise-craig

Comment: Here is the fiddle of the HTML and CSS. I hope I did this right. https://jsfiddle.net/farquhar86/3vy2547f/

Comment: use `width=100%` on img elements

Answer (score 0):

Set `.profile .main-section .content {width: 60%}` or so.  Because you have photos of different widths, you want to use a value for `width` for that container to accommodate various photo widths that presents them reasonably consistently.

You don't want that container to change sizes with each photo because this would make the controls (left-right arrows) jump for the user, which is why the folks who made the carousel opted (rightly) to keep the dimensions of the `.content` div consistent regardless of photo size.

So your other option here is to crop your photos so that they are all the same width.  I usually opt for cropping my photos to standardized dimensions because as you add photos to the carousel, you may find that a compromise `width` value is tough to find.